# Dataframe take rows that have exactly one occurence of a value from list

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

Code:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'data': ['hey how r u', 'hello', 'hey abc d e f hey f', 'g h i i j k', 'hello how r u hello']})
vals = ['hey', 'hello']
```

I want to take all the rows that have exactly one word that is in the list `vals`. In this case, these would be `'hey how r u'`, `'hello'`

What I tried:

```
def exactly_one(text):
    for v in vals:
        if text.count(v) > 1:
            return False
    return True


df = df[df['data'].contains('|'.join(vals)) & (exactly_one(df['data'].str))]
```

Breaks with an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.count` with a regex:

```
df[df['data'].str.count('|'.join(vals)).eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
          data
0  hey how r u
1        hello
```

Intermediate:

```
df['data'].str.count('|'.join(vals))

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    2
Name: data, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What if I want to consider each value occurence as one? I mean, if "hey" appears 3 times, it is considered as one, since it is one value from the list?